# JavaFx, Path Transition, straight line

Tags: java, animation, javafx

I'm working on a javaFx application. How can I make a straight line transition? I have two rectangles and I want first rectangle to go to the second rectangle.
Here's the code that doesn't work:

```
 Rectangle r1 = rectangles.get(numbers[0]);
    Rectangle r2 = rectangles.get(numbers[1]);

    TranslateTransition translateTransition = new TranslateTransition();

    translateTransition.setNode(r1);
    translateTransition.setDuration(Duration.millis(1000));
    translateTransition.setFromX(r1.getX());
    translateTransition.setToX(r2.getX());

    TranslateTransition translateTransition2 = new TranslateTransition();

    translateTransition2.setNode(r2);
    translateTransition2.setDuration(Duration.millis(1000));
    translateTransition2.setFromX(0);
    translateTransition2.setToX(r1.getX() - r2.getX());
    translateTransition2.play();

    translateTransition.play();
```

Comment: I'd advise using the simpler [TranslateTransition](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/animation/TranslateTransition.html) for this task.

Comment: I have a problem. Both rectangles are in a group and if I want to move the first to the second rectangle(only x coordinate) and second rectangle to the first rectangle, in other words to swap the rectangles, both rectangles would meet in the center and stop. I edited the code above.